# Secondary bower / build blocks in index.html?

Tags: angularjs, build, gruntjs, bower, pdf.js

I'm trying to get my build setup (Yeoman / angular-fullstack generator) to separate out one file, pdf.worker.js because pdf.js needs to call it directly. Once minified it ends up looking for a file like:

```
dbdj4jkwn.vendor.worker.js
```

Which obviously doesn't exist. I tried to add a second build statement in my index.html, as I'm managing pdf.js via bower, but it didn't work. The build system inserted all the bower_component scripts from the other bower block, and while it produced jdkjfjf34jk.vendor.worker.js the file was empty.

```
<!-- build:js({client}) app/vendor.worker.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
        <script src="bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Where am I going wrong? I thought perhaps the correct way was to write an exclusion into the Gruntfile.js so pdf.worker.js wasn't minified, but I can't see how to a) make it generate the second file and ensure it's copied across, and b) keep the right filename reference. I suspect I might just have to exclude both pdf.js and pdf.worker.js, but then the question is still 1) How do I get it to do that, and still copy the uncompressed pdf.js~ files across to the dist?

---

Additional in reply to DanEEStar:

Brilliant, thank you! I've added the below in, but I'm still finding it converting the pdf files and when I deploy and test the site, it gives me the error that it can't load:

```
http://myserver/app/6004c81b.vendor.worker.js
```

Here's what I have in the grunt file (along with including it in the task)

```
pdfWorker: {
        src: 'app/bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>app/bower_components/pdf-dist/build/pdf.worker.js'
    }
```

I took the worker file out of index.html but grunt build puts it back in! There's no direct reference, so I'm guessing I don't yet understand how some of its being built. There are directives in gruntfile.js to build directories for bower which I guess is where it's happening - if I can ensure it doesn't minify/uglify the pdf.js too then it won't be looking for 6004c81b.vendor.worker.js.

Last thing - I have the workerSrc property being set but I don't know if it's ignoring it or it's all just being converted by the uglify process.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to prevent the pdf.worker.js file from being minified and renamed? Or do you want to have two minified files?

Comment: Apparently pdf.js et al don't do well with minification anyway. All I want is for them to work on the deployed site, so I'm happy for them to just get copied across, but still be managed by bower in my dev environment.

Comment: so my solution is still viable for that. just do the same with the pds.js file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That didn't work unfortunately, but it got me started, so thank you :) For anyone else searching, here's how I got it working;

I modified the "rev" task in my Gruntfile.js (setup by Yeoman/angular-fullstack generator) and added exclude patterns to the src to stop it renaming pdf.js and pdf.worker.js like so:

```
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/**/*.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

I left the pdf.js and pdf.worker.js inside the bower block in index.html, but added this after it:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    PDFJS.workerSrc = 'bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';
</script>
```

That's all it took! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this pdf.worker.js file is, that it is only referenced in the pdf.js JavaScript file one possible way to solve the problem might be this.

I have a similar setup in my Gruntfile, but I did not test it so beware.

1. Do not add the pdf.worder.js file into your index.html file! You (or Grunt) have to copy this file directly to the dist folder. You can do this by adding an additional copy-rule in your Gruntfile.js:

`copy: {
    dist: {
        ...
    },
    styles: {
        ...
    },
    pdfworker: {
        src: 'bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js',
        dest: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/pdf.worker.js'
    }
}`

2. call copy:pdfworker in the build step:

`grunt.registerTask('build', [
        ...
        'copy:dist',
        'copy:pdfworker',
        'cdnify',
        ...
    ]);`

3. In your index.html file you can the specify the path to this pdf.worker.js file:

   PDFJS.workerSrc = 'bower_components/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js';

You still have to include the initial pdf.js file in your bower_components in the index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found for this issue is from an issue i came across [here](https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf/issues/137).

The solution is surprisingly simple! Just include the combined version.

`pdf.combined.js`

In the case of using wiredep (cuz really why manually enter deps, us developers are lazy!) you will just need to override the main file from the bower.json in the pdf folder.

```
exports.wiredep = {
  directory: 'bower_components',
  overrides: {
    'pdfjs-dist': {
      main: ['build/pdf.combined.js']
    }
  }
};
```

Beer time!